# #selector(didTapRegister) not in scope

Tags: swift, objective-c

When I run this code by `#selector(didTapRegister)` I get a `didTapRegister` is not in scope. I have a bigger application I am using it in and on one page it works and another it won't, well it won't work anywhere else.
I am stuck on figuring out why. Can anyone help solve it? seems to be an Objective-C issue possibly because I have same issues trying to make IBOutlets, I have tried searching for answers and I just don't have enough knowledge to understand why it isn't working, I've tried moving the code to different scopes and still nothing. with the IBOutlets it's saying IBOutlet property cannot have non-object type UIButton?.Type

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let Button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
        Button.setTitle("Chat", for: .normal)
        Button.layer.backgroundColor = CGColor.init(gray: 0.0, alpha: 0.0)
        Button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        Button.setTitleColor(.red, for: .highlighted)
        Button.layer.borderWidth = 1
        Button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        Button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        Button.isHighlighted = false
        Button.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = true
        
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: Button)
        Button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapRegister), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        
        navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        
        func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try what he said but

Just use SwiftUI it is much better

@objc and all of that is fine but in SwiftUI you can just right click and add buttons

Answer (score 1):

There 2 mistakes in the code.

1. You have to create `@objc` function for the button action
2. In your code move `viewWillAppear` method outside the `viewDidLoad`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
        button.setTitle("Chat", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.red, for: .highlighted)
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        button.isHighlighted = false
        button.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = true
        
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapRegister), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        
        navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        
    }
    
    @objc func didTapRegister(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

Note: button name start with lowercase.

Comment: I could kiss you thank you so much, I've been working on something all day and have just gotten lost in the sauce. I knew it was something simple I really appreciate it!